# Bulk adding multiple "events" in the django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin

### What I have

I have a model of events. Each event can have many occurrences.

```
models.py:
...
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event')
    ...
class Event(TranslatableModel):
    ...
```

### What I want

I want a nice way to add multiple similar events with a single date (occurrence).

### Some thoughts

I thought of adding a single event with many occurrences and then turn them into a single events (with a Button "Turn Occurrences into Events"). So I need to iterate over the occurences and save an event for each. But how do I loop over the occurences from the Admin interface, save them and delete the original event?

Alternative I thought of creating a bulk adding Interface like this:

```
admin.py:
...
class BulkAddEvent(Event):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class BulkAddEventAdmin(EventAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass
        # I don't know what to do here.

...
```

In any case I need to override the save_model function. But the question of iterating over the occurences remains. Can someone help?

### Versions

Python Version 2.7.12
Django Version 1.8.16

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here, but are you trying to implement a many-to-many relationship? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I must admit that I am not a 100% sure how this model works because I did not wrote the Project initially. But as far as I can see it is a many-to-one relationship. An Event can have many occurrences but every occurrences has only one event.